# Attach a Context Menu to a GUI.Window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a custom window which has multiple `GUI.Window`'s inside of it. I can create a context menu for the main window and that works. But when I try to create context menus for the `GUI.Window` it doesn't work. When I right click on the window it just starts to drag it around the main window.

Here I have a list which stores the window information:

```
// Stores a list of my windows
List<StoryboardWindow> windows = new List<StoryboardWindow>();
```

Then here I loop through the windows and call `DrawNodeWindow`:

```
// Draws the windows to the screen
void OnGUI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++) {
        windows[i].window = GUI.Window(i, windows[i].window, DrawNodeWindow, windows[i].windowTitle);
    }
}
```

I then have this method which creates a GenericMenu for the window, but it doesn't work when I right click on the window.

```
// Supposed to create the context menu for the window
void DrawNodeWindow(int id) {
    Event currentEvent = Event.current;
    if (currentEvent.type == EventType.ContextClick){
        GenericMenu menu = new GenericMenu();
        menu.AddItem(new GUIContent("Remove"), false, RemoveDialogWindow, id);
        menu.ShowAsContext();
        currentEvent.Use();
    }
    GUI.DragWindow();
}
```

This is the class that stores the information:

```
// Data for each window
public class StoryboardWindow {
    public enum WindowType { CharacterDialog, CharactersDialog }
    public WindowType windowType;
    public string windowTitle;
    public Rect window;
}
```

So, do I have to do this differently? Can I even do this? What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the old deprecated UI system? You could easily do what you are intending with the new UI system.

Comment: Is the new UI system supported in the `EditorWindow`? I am doing `public class MyClass : EditorWindow {}`

Comment: The new UI system doesn't need scripts to inherit from EditorWindow. A simple Monobehaviour script is perfectly fine for any interaction with other UI elements. I would suggest looking into a few basic tutorials. I believe unity have some in their tutorials section.